# Is it possible that each coordinate is independent for von Mises Fisher distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

Let $(X_1,...,X_n)$ be an $n$-dimensional random vector whose distribution is a von Mises Fisher distribution on $S^{n+1}$

Is it possible that $X_1,...,X_{n-1}$ are independent?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you meant to write

  For
  $n > 1$
  , let
  $(X_1,...,X_n)$
  be an
  $n$
  -dimensional random vector whose distribution is a von Mises Fisher distribution on
  $S^{n-1}$
  Is it possible that $X_1,...,X_{n}$ are independent?

To see that $X_1,...,X_{n}$ are not independent, note that
$P\Bigl(x_2 > \frac{3}{4}\Bigr) > 0$,
but
$P\Bigl(x_2 > \frac{3}{4}{\,{\Large{\mid\,}}}x_1 > \frac{3}{4}\Bigr)=0$.